How to find out what is changing my PATH?
OS: 14.4, shell: zsh, additional software: homebrew, vim, oh-my-zsh, iTerm2, et cetera
One day I noticed that my PATH contains strange part:
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:Vim�UnDo�:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS:/Applications/Little Snitch.app/Contents/Components


The part is: ?Vim?UnDo? (actually there are UTF symbols instead of ?)

I grepped most parts of filesystem, home directory including files and directories starting with dot, /etc, /Library, /opt/homebrew for "UnDo", but found nothing.
It there a way to debug the process of changing PATH? Something like gathering trace or log of such changes or something like that?

Is the PATH broken in a freshly started shell, or is it correct first, but magically changes later on?

If it were statically added in zsh initialization it should be located in either ~/.z* or /etc/z*, and should have turned up in your manual search. If it is not in the zsh initialization files it is being added from an unexpected source.
Running zsh -x will (re)initialize zsh with XTRACE enabled and give you immense amounts of output of every command and initialization step being executed, and via what file or function.

Helped partially. With 'zsh -x' I was able to notice that it is path_helper sets PATH with strange component. Then I found its source in the internet. It turns out that it recursivly scans files hierarchy under /etc/path.d. And this directory contains binary backup file .100-homebrew.un~ which it tries to parse as a regular paths list.
